# Messages sent by php @mail do not resolve html

Tags: php, html, email, centos

I am porting a web server from an hosting one to a private one on Centos and I am tryng to attune each thing. Now I am trying to send email by @mail; I managed to do it by tweacking a bit with the configuration, but when the message is shown on the client it shows the html source instead of displaying it. The source of the message, a part of which I am reporting at the bottom, seems fine; what could it be?

```
-PHP-Originating-Script: 500:mailListItInarrivo.php
From: info@inarrivo.net
Reply-To: info@inarrivo.net
Content-Type: multipart/alternative; boundary="PHP-alt-ac65ac6e336bbb702036bb1b60fa2bc6"

--PHP-alt-ac65ac6e336bbb702036bb1b60fa2bc6
Content-Type: text/plain; charset="iso-8859-1"
Content-Transfer-Encoding: 7bit
Content-Type: text/html; charset="iso-8859-1"
Content-Transfer-Encoding: 7bit
<!DOCTYPE html PUBLIC "-//W3C//DTD XHTML 1.0 Strict//EN" "http://www.w3.org/TR/xhtml1/DTD/xhtml1-   strict.dtd">
<html xmlns="http://www.w3.org/1999/xhtml">
<head>
```

As you may see, the html part lacks the:
--PHP-alt-531031ef9065eeb8948b4338f95fdd14 section.
But this is even funnier as the php script is the same as the old one and the command is present:

```
--PHP-alt-<?php echo $random_hash; ?> 
Content-Type: text/plain; charset="iso-8859-1"
Content-Transfer-Encoding: 7bit
<?php echo $greeting; ?>
<?php echo $content; ?>
--PHP-alt-<?php echo $random_hash; ?> 
Content-Type: text/html; charset="iso-8859-1"
Content-Transfer-Encoding: 7bit
<!DOCTYPE html PUBLIC "-//W3C//DTD XHTML 1.0 Strict//EN" "http://www.w3.org/TR/xhtml1/DTD/xhtml1-strict.dtd">
<html xmlns="http://www.w3.org/1999/xhtml">
<head>
<meta http-equiv="Content-Type" content="text/html; charset=utf-8">
```

Comment: You have two content-types in the same block, that may be the problem.

Comment: Building MIME mail bodys by hand is only advisable if you know what you're doing. Everyone else uses PHPMailer or SwiftMailer.

Comment: Ye, they allow you to easily send multi part content.  Which allows you to create html and plain text variants in the same email.  The client will then display to the user whichever is best supported.

Answer (score 1):

Don't send out conflicting mime-types:

```
--PHP-alt-ac65ac6e336bbb702036bb1b60fa2bc6
Content-Type: text/plain; charset="iso-8859-1"    <--- it's a bird!
Content-Transfer-Encoding: 7bit
Content-Type: text/html; charset="iso-8859-1"     <--- it's a plane!
```

Since you're getting the raw html code, obviously the FIRST content-type is the one taking effect in your mail client.

Comment: In fact I also noticed the html format missed the:
--PHP-alt-531031ef9065eeb8948b4338f95fdd14 part, notwithstanding the php echos it also in the latter case.